# Factor scores for binary data where "Yes"s are limited to <=3 of 18 items

Tags: binary-data, factor-analysis

I have survey (n=600) where individuals were asked binary yes (1) /no (0) questions regarding 18 specific service needs (e.g. transportation, groceries, peer counseling, etc.) Participants were limited to choosing yes to only 3 of the 18 services. Because of internal logistics - these 18 services can be factored into 3 groups. We want to know which of these 3 groups people said "yes" to. I wasn't going to run PCA since these 18 services are already factored, but I need factor (based) scores for each group.
Is it statistically appropriate to just use sum factor-based scoring for each group? Do I need to take into consideration that individuals were only allotted 3 yes responses, thus the highest per-case value for any group would be 3. 
Thanks so much for you help!

Comment: 1.  I'm removing the mention of SPSS, as it is not necessary here.  2.  I suggest being very clear about whether you are referring to a) each person's sum [which ranges from 0 to 3] of a set of Yes scores within a group of about 6 services, or b) "factor scores", which are continuous, which are weighted according to factor loadings, which can be computed automatically, and which range from 0 to 1.